# Core plot alternatingBandFills "jumps" when scrolling horizontally

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a simple core plot with xAxis alternatingBandFills

```
xAxis.alternatingBandFills        = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[bandFillColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1], [NSNull null], nil];
```

The effect:

[image: plot]

Now when I scroll horizontally (panning to the left), when the region of x between 0 and 10 goes to the left outside of the viewable range, the fill color would "jump" and 10 to 20 would become highlighted instead (and 20 to 30 would become white, and so on).

Is there a way to keep the band as it is without the alternation while scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot space and shuffle the fill colors as needed. I added [issue 601](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=601) to the Core Plot issue tracker requesting a feature to make this easier.

Comment: Could you explain the workaround I don't get how to shuffle the fill colors and which methods to use. Thks

Comment: Use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot space. Implement the `-plotSpace:didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate:` delegate method. After each change, examine the plot range and shuffle the `alternatingBandFills` array if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, I made it almost working I used a modulo to detect the order according to my major period but I can't make it work  perfectly when scroll right or back… Could you do a test, seems not trivial to make it work… I'm gonna use a barplot otherwise as a workaround if I can't use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I implemented some **BarPlot** on the visible screen but the **performance** are bad on iPhone 4&4S compare to **alternatingBandFills** even with very few data so I came back to this alternatingBandFills by **shuffling** the array in the **- plotSpace:didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate:** has Eric said. Here the solution I implemented:

```
-(void)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate {
if (self.plotSpace.xRange.locationDouble <0) {//area before your xrange origin to pass from 0 to -1 and not 0 to -0
         value = value-1;
    }

    int value = plotSpace.xRange.locationDouble.x/majorInterval;
    if (self.currentFillBand != value%2) {
        NSArray * array = xaxis.alternatingBandFills;
        xaxis.alternatingBandFills = @[array[1], array[0]];
        self.currentFillBand = value%2;
    }
}
```

If your globalXRange is larger/before than your xrange.origin, so your xRange.location will be <0 when you scroll backward but the value variable will pass from 0 to -0 and so I retrieve -1 to the value in such case.

Note: I still have a small issue with a new majorTick before your globalXRange, I got a shuffling I can't fix, so I avoid that case.